# Arrow graphic structure simple

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, arrows

I would like to know if someone could help me with a simple arrow graphic. I know the possibilities with this programm are infinite and harder than what I ask! I just need to do the following and I'm not sure how as I'm new at this... Thanks so much in advance

[image: ![enter image description here]

I don't care the numbers and the name, I want to know how to struct it more than nothing!

Answer (score 2):

With `forest` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}
Resultats:
\bigskip

\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=east,anchor=east}
[,for children={no edge}
  [DMM,for children={edge={->,>=stealth}}
    [AC[6V]]
    [DC[6V]]
  ]
  [OSC,for children={edge={->,>=stealth}}
    [AC[6V]]
    [DC[6V]]  
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your work! Helped me a lot :)